# Данные формы отправляются через ajax, но не записываются в POST, в чем дело?

Tags: php, ajax, ооп

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Отправляю данные формы через ajax, отправка работает, данные отображаются в консоли, но не пишутся в массив POST.
Код js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function sendAjaxForm(ajax_form, url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#" + ajax_form).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
               console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.log("failure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $("#form__signin").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendAjaxForm('form__signin', "Index/ajax");
        return false;
    });
});
```

IndexController

```
  public function ajax() {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->pageData['title'] = "Вход в личный кабинет";
        $this->ajax();
        $this->view->render($this->pageTpl, $this->pageData);
    }[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

Comment: В консоли же выводится `print_r($_POST)` и данные там есть.

Comment: @u_mulder вот только хотел об этом же написать 

Comment: @АлексейШиманский походу тут есть ожидание что `ajax()` внутри `index()` тоже выведет что-то.

Comment: @u_mulder в этом и дело, что в консоль данные попадают, значит запрос отработал, но вот когда я делаю метод в контроллере и пытаюсь сделать var_dump($_POST), то ничего не получаю.

Comment: А как представляешь между собой связь методов `index()` и `ajax()`?

Comment: @u_mulder ожидал что если вызвать метод ajax в методе index(), я и смогу получить необходимые данные из $_POST

Comment: Тогда стоит много раз перечитать http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#where

Comment: @u_mulder как я понял мне нужно обработать полученные данные ajax через header(content-type)? И сделать это напрямую в методе index?

Comment: А чем не устраивает обработать данные в методе `ajax()`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138238/discussion-between-zak-attack-and-u-mulder).

Answer (score 0):

в $_POST записываются те данные, которые были засабмичены из формы.
А данные, которые вы хотите получить из аякс запроса можете получить так:
file_get_contents("php://input")